# Implementing Instances of a Class

Tags: java, instance, multiple-instances

I'm fairly new to programming (roughly one year), and I've come to a logic gap.  Say I were building a database of employees: How would I go about creating instances of the employees without hard-coding employee1, employee2, etc..

I've been suggested to use an array, but in Java an array must have a set length, so I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this.  Any help would be great!
-Matt

Edit: Thanks for the help everybody. I was unaware of the ArrayList type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayLists can change in size. Here is a simple loop to add 20 objects to an array List:

```
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i < 20; i ++) {
    array.add(new Object());
}
```

This is an easy way to create an lot of objects at once, and you don't have to have a specified size, so you can easily change how many are contained in the `ArrayList`

Comment: So essentially, one could simply add an object to the array every time they want to add a new employee?

Comment: @MatthewParnham Yes. ArrayLists can change size. Arrays have to have a size declared when you create them

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList of type Employee

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList` (no need to specify the length of the List in this case)

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
    employee.setFirstname(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
    .....
    employees.add(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a class to hold the Employee information.**

> Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String deptName;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String deptName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
               "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
               ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
               ", deptName='" + deptName + '\'' +
               '}';
    }
}
```

**Example code to create multiple employees and print them**

> Employees.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Employees {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

        employeeList.add(new Employee("FN-1","LN-1","Dept-1"));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("FN-2","LN-2","Dept-2"));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("FN-3","LN-3","Dept-3"));

        //loop
        for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
            employeeList.add(new Employee("FN-" + i, "LN-" + i, "Dept-" + i));
        }

        //print
        employeeList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Employee{firstName='FN-1', lastName='LN-1', deptName='Dept-1'}
Employee{firstName='FN-2', lastName='LN-2', deptName='Dept-2'}
Employee{firstName='FN-3', lastName='LN-3', deptName='Dept-3'}
Employee{firstName='FN-4', lastName='LN-4', deptName='Dept-4'}
Employee{firstName='FN-5', lastName='LN-5', deptName='Dept-5'}
Employee{firstName='FN-6', lastName='LN-6', deptName='Dept-6'}
Employee{firstName='FN-7', lastName='LN-7', deptName='Dept-7'}
```